# xbox-360 ethernet to win7 tower to wireless

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, xbox360

alrighty
i have an xbox etherneted to a pc running win7
this physical connection is solid because upon turning on the xbox the pc recognizes "unidentified network" in a local area connection. this connection goes when the xbox is off

the connection from pc to wireless to internet is solid because im posting this from said computer

from what i can sumize my pc thinks the xbox is a router and wants to find the outside world through it
uppon testing, the xbox thinks the pc is a router and wants an IP from the pc

relentless googling yielded 1 result for back when xboxes were between slivers and metro that didnt get anny results

EDIT
solved. ended up disabling ICS on the wireless and bridging the network became possable after that

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you want is an Internet connection for your Xbox?

This is simple to achieve in windows using ICS ([Internet Connection Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7))

Comment: nope. my wireless connection's sharing options are all checked. the local connection's properties are set to give ip adresses
after a quick diagnostic of the local connection it tells me to reset the modem which wont help because an xbox isnt a modem
after skipping the step it tels me that the connection doesnt have a valid IP